# Codeigniter selecting schema in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, codeigniter-2

My application is using CodeIgniter 2 and want to connect it to postgresql. Database name is `tirta` and schema is `wening`. My problem is it always connect to schema `public`. How can I fix it?

Here is my database configuration:

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'postgres';
$db['default']['password'] = 'mypass';
$db['default']['database'] = 'tirta';
$db['default']['schema'] = 'wening';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'postgre';
```

Comment: You could change the [search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) for your user in Postgres

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out but have no idea how to implement it in my script

Answer (score 0):

You can just include that schema in the search path.

If you can use a "setup statement" that is run after the connection has been established, you can use:

```
set search_path=wening,public;
```

Another option is to permanently change the user to use that [search path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH) (regardless on how or from which tool that user connects):

```
alter user postgres
  set search_path = wening,public;
```

---

Unrelated, but: it is a bad idea to use the superuser as the application user.

Comment: i did it and search_path has changed to `wening,public` but still the application refers to `public` schema. is there something to change in the codeigniter configuration?